# Custom color between frametitle and top ribbon

Tags: beamer, color

I want to change colors for various elements in a presentation with Frankfurt style. I found how to change background and text color in the frametitle and outline ribbon, but I get two pale, horizontal green lines over and under the frame title. Any idea how I could remove them?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=OliveGreen!40!Sepia, bg=OliveGreen!70!YellowGreen}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=LimeGreen, bg = LimeGreen}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=LimeGreen}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=Sepia, bg = LimeGreen!60!GreenYellow}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=OliveGreen!60!Sepia, bg = LimeGreen!60!GreenYellow}


\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Today} 

\begin{document}
  \section[My first section]{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives (red arrows added manually) :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem has something to do with different colour models. There was a question somewhere on this side which explains it in detail, but unfortunately I can not find it right now.

In short: a workaround is to use a colour defined in `RGB` for the mixing.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=OliveGreen!40!Sepia, bg=OliveGreen!70!YellowGreen}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=LimeGreen, bg = LimeGreen}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=LimeGreen}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=Sepia, bg = LimeGreen!60!GreenYellow}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=OliveGreen!60!Sepia, bg = LimeGreen!60!GreenYellow}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{163,216,56}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
        color(0ex)=(mygreen);%
        color(1ex)=(mygreen);%
        color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)
  }
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@belowframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
        color(0ex)=(bg);%
        color(1ex)=(mygreen)
  }
}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Today} 

\begin{document}
  \section[My first section]{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively you can select a `\selectcolormodel{RGB}`, but than you might have to adjust you colour selection in order to get the same results as above.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\selectcolormodel{RGB}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=OliveGreen!40!Sepia, bg=OliveGreen!70!YellowGreen}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=LimeGreen, bg = LimeGreen}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=LimeGreen}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=Sepia, bg = LimeGreen!60!GreenYellow}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=OliveGreen!60!Sepia, bg = LimeGreen!60!GreenYellow}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Today} 

\begin{document}
    \section[My first section]{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame title}
        Some text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With some adjustments the first option worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

## Update

`tikz` now supports CMYK shadings out of the box since version 3.1.3. You still need to set the colour model to CMYK:

```
\RequirePackage[cmyk,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

---

A new solution is now available to this question using a new package, `pgf-cmykshadings`, which supports shadings in CMYK for `pgf`.

The fundamental problem is this: The `dvipsnames` colours from `xcolor` are all defined in the CMYK colour space. `beamer` then uses `pgf` to create shadings using these colours. Except `pgf` does not support shadings in CMYK, only in RGB. So the shadings get converted to RGB, while the solid colours remain as CMYK and you get a colour mismatch.

The other answer to this question has already demonstrated how to use RGB colours everywhere, but you can continue to use the `dvipsnames` colours in the CMYK colour colour space and use CMYK shadings using the `pgf-cmykshadings` package.

Change the start of the MWE example to:

```
\RequirePackage[cmyk,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

`xcolor` must be loaded first using the `dvipsnames` option to avoid an option clash. I've also used the `cmyk` option just to make sure that all colours will be in CMYK. And `pgf-cmykshadings` needs to be loaded before `beamer` to ensure that the shadings are set up in the CMYK colour space.

You'll now get CMYK output (as specified by the `dvipsnames` colours) everywhere including in shadings:

[image]