# Layers at the top of a beamer template

Tags: beamer

I am trying to make a presentation and there is an annoying feature of the template I am using which I would like to get rid of. Here is the code I use

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme[]{whale}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray!20!}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=Green!90!black!200!}
\setbeamercolor{palette miniframes primary}{fg=magenta}
 


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Section I}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}

\end{frame}

\section{Section II}

\begin{frame}{Second Frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is
[image]

As you can see, at the top of the frame, there are three layers: the top one in black, the middle one in light green, and the bottom one in green. As can be seen in the photo, the middle layer covers part of the white circles appearing in the top one (they count the slides in each section). I would like to either get rid of the middle layer or force it to not cover the circles counting the slides in the top layer.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: there are no three layers on top, only two. The black headline and the green frametitle. What you see as third light green line is the shadow between these two and it is only visible because it is calculated in the wrong colour model. You can fix this by explicitly telling xcolor which colour model you would like to have, e.g. `rgb`, `cmyk` etc.

Then you can use the following code to add a bit more padding below the headline:

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={cmyk,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme[]{whale}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray!20!}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=Green!90!black!200!}
\setbeamercolor{palette miniframes primary}{fg=magenta}
 

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Section I}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}

\end{frame}

\section{Section II}

\begin{frame}{Second Frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the reason for the appearance of that middle layer?

Comment: @QGravity See my updated answer. It is a problem with colour systems.

Comment: @QGravity See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456720/36296 for a more detailed explanation

Comment: thank you very much ...

Comment: @QGravity You're welcome!